# problem converting unicode characters from native to Java

Tags: java, objective-c, java-native-interface, native

I have a JNI code written in Objective-C (though I believe I would have the same problem in a C/C++ program) that returns jstring to the Java code. I am using the char* to jstring conversion as specified [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2005/tn2147.html) in the "Creating Java Strings From Native Strings" section. My problem is that while on the native side the strings are correct (i.e. native string presents in the standard output correctly) when passed to Java and sent to standard output I get '?' for the non-English characters.

Thanks

Comment: it's possible that your console does not correctly display the characters.  you should print out the actual character code to determine whether or not your chars are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Java strings are UTF-16 encoded,You need to take endianness into account.